# Ethernet not recognized

Tags: updates, internet, ethernet

I am running ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. After latest update, I do not have internet. I even have no ethernet option in Network Manager. Ifconfig -a gives me just lo interface. Between updating and restarting computer I changed kernel from linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic to linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic.

```
lspci -v

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Onboard Ethernet
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10, NUMA node 0
    I/O ports at de00 [size=256]
    Memory at fdbff000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at fdbe0000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at fde00000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/2 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=2 Masked-
    Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 12-34-56-78-12-34-56-78

lshw -C network

 *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:de00(size=256) memory:fdbff000-fdbfffff memory:fdbe0000-fdbeffff memory:fde00000-fde0ffff
```

Comment: Is `r8168-dkms` installed? Remove it.

Comment: What if you do `ifconfig -a`, can you see it?

Comment: modinfo r8168 | grep -i version gives me Module r8168 not found, iconfig -a gives me just lo interface, no ethernet

Answer (score 0):

same problem here, it hit me last night (again). last time i removed new kernel then rebooted with an old kernel and the issue was gone, but this time i was helpless. searching through internet i was told to "remove r8168-dkms" but i never had r8168-dkms ever installed. so how about the opposite, to install the r8168-dkms?

since this network card is the only one on board, so there was no network access in the system. used yumi and ubuntu 20.04 desktop iso image to make an usb live cd to boot, fortunately the network was usable in it. then downloaded the r8168-dkms package in the live system, via the following commands:

```
sudo -i
# mount the real os, and get into it
mount /dev/sdX /mnt
chroot /mnt
# apt download package and dependencies into /var/cache, without installing them
apt install --download-only r8168-dkms
reboot
```

rebooted back into the real ubuntu system, run this:

```
sudo -i
# install the cached package
apt install r8168-dkms
reboot
```

done, hope this can help someone